# Reduce tray icon padding on Ubuntu with GNOME 3

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, system-tray

All of my tray icons have a higher than normal amount of padding on Ubuntu 19.04.
[image]
Is there any way to tweak this value?

Comment: Maybe this extension helps: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/

Comment: @RoVo Thanks! Tthis fixes it for me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As suggested by @pLumo,
'[Status Area Horizontal Spacing](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/)' GNOME extension fixed my problem.
[image]

Comment: It works wel... but after activating it, you have to hover the mouse over the icons to work. At least it did the trick for me

Comment: doesn't work on ubuntu 20 without hovering on icons

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) Extension which fixes this issue and provides many other improvements for the Unity-lovers.

> Unite is a GNOME Shell extension which makes a few layout tweaks to the top panel and removes window decorations to make it look like Ubuntu Unity Shell.

[image: Unite preview]

Comment: doesn't work on ubuntu 20