# Tuck all GNOME extensions into a box [or] Grouping all GNOME extensions

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I want to put all my gnome extensions in a single toolbox like in Windows. Now I have 6 extensions which takes lot of space like shown below in the bar and looks not so good. Also, they leave less space for favorite programs. Is that possible?

[image].

Versus

[image]

After [`Pablo Bianchi`](https://askubuntu.com/users/349837/pablo-bianchi) comment to use 'Status Area Horizontal Spacing' extension

[image]

I don't know if this beens asked before but I didn't get any similar questions while typing.

I suppose there is no such extension as of now and it would be nice if someone develops such one.

Comment: Not all extensions are indicators on the topbar. IDK a way for grouping, but [you can](https://askubuntu.com/a/1140920/349837) change the distance between them

Comment: Thanks! that really helped. I edited my question to reflect the change.